# Get enum class size at compile time without defining additional element

Tags: c++, c++11

One common approach is to add MAX as the last element, but it is not always desirable.

Any other ways? Can I do

```
constexpr size_t enum_size = sizeof(EnumClassName) / sizeof(std::underlying_type(EnumClassName)?
```

Is this safe? Not sure if I need to worry about padding. My impression is there should not be padding for enum class, because the enum item size are all the same. Assume I only use uint8_t or uint16_t as underlying type.

Comment: Won't the answer always be 1?

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right... enum is not aggregate..

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for (or at least, what most `MAX` enumerators provide) is the largest actual enumerator value. That's different from the largest possible value that the enumeration could store. The latter would be defined by `std::numeric_limits<typename std::underlying_type<Enumeration>::type>::max()`.

There is no way to automatically get the largest enumerator value in an enumeration. Well, not automatically.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest does not do what you expect. Sadly, there is no support for any such thing in C++, nor is there an easy and straightforward way of doing it (numeric limits will do, but *only* if your enumeration values are contiguous and start at zero).

There are libraries such as [Better Enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) which, among other things such as name-to-string conversion, also provide determining the number of enumeration values.
They are kinda heavy though, since you need a *loooooooooooot* of macro abuse to implement this. On the positive side, you only pay the price in compile-time, not in binary size.